# Sun-Earth-Moon-Spacecraft four-body simulation using MATLAB - unexpected results

Tags: newtonian-gravity, computational-physics, celestial-mechanics, software, three-body-problem

I'm trying to simulate this four-body system by directly integrating the system of equations
$$\ddot{\textbf{x}} = \sum_{i=1\:i\neq k}^4 G\frac{m_i}{|\textbf{x}_i-\textbf{x}_k|^3}(\textbf{x}_i-\textbf{x}_k)$$
with respect to an inertial coordinate system (ICRF) centered in the Earth ($\textbf{x}_4=0$). The initial state has been obtained using NASA's Horizons System.

I've used a similar approach to successfully simulate two-body systems, but when trying this approach with three and four bodies the results obtained are wrong. The Moon for example leaves its position in the Earth-Moon system after just a few hours.

My guess is that I'm not using the model correctly or there's a problem in the translation into code of the system of equations.

```
% Data - masses in kg, distances in km
G = 6.67139e-20;
m1 = 1000; % Spacecraft
m2 = 1.989e30; % Sun
m3 = 7.348e22; % Moon
m4 = 5.972e24; % Earth

% Problem definition and integration
F = @(t,u) [
    u(10); u(11); u(12); % vel1
    u(13); u(14); u(15); % vel2
    u(16); u(17); u(18); % vel3
    %
    G*m2*(u(4:6) - u(1:3))/(norm(u(4:6) - u(1:3))^3)+...
    G*m3*(u(7:9) - u(1:3))/(norm(u(7:9) - u(1:3))^3)+...
    G*m4*(- u(1:3))/(norm(-u(1:3))^3);
    %
    G*m1*(u(1:3) - u(4:6))/(norm(u(1:3) - u(4:6))^3)+...
    G*m3*(u(7:9) - u(4:6))/(norm(u(7:9) - u(4:6))^3)+...
    G*m4*(- u(4:6))/(norm(-u(4:6))^3);
    %
    G*m1*(u(1:3) - u(7:9))/(norm(u(1:3) - u(7:9))^3)+...
    G*m2*(u(4:6) - u(7:9))/(norm(u(4:6) - u(7:9))^3)+...
    G*m4*(- u(7:9))/(norm(-u(7:9))^3);
    ];

% Initial state vector
u0 = [
    15000; 15000; 15000;                 % x0 spacescraft
    -1.37238e8; -5.83535e7; 3.95205e3;   % x0 sun
    -2.54897e5; -2.944768e5; -1.49676e4; % x0 moon
    2; 5; -2.1;                          % v0 spacecraft
    1.21508e1; -2.7309e1; 4.1503e-4;     % v0 sun
    7.89e-1; -6.27747e-1; -8.31497e-2;   % v0 moon
    ];
times = 0:10:5*24*3600;
[tsol, usol] = ode89(F,times,u0);

% Draw Earth
[x,y,z] = sphere;
x = x*6371;
y = y*6371;
z = z*6371;

plot3(usol(:,1),usol(:,2),usol(:,3))
grid on
hold on
plot3(usol(:,7),usol(:,8),usol(:,9))
surf(x,y,z)
axis equal
```

Comment: Or the numerical method is unstable and unsuitable to the 3- or 4-body problem.

Comment: If "The Moon [...] leaves its position [...] after just a few hours" then it is unlikely that  instability in the numerical method is the problem. Unless the step-time is enormous, even the most naieve 'repeat {Iterate position, iterate velocity, recalculate acceleration}' method should provide reasonable accuracy for at least to-the-order-of one moon orbit period.

Comment: I do not see the inertial force that should appear in the non-inertial reference frame centered on Earth.

Comment: The reference frame is inertial. Also, I've tried every ode integrator in matlab and the results don't change. I've settled on ode89 here because it looks like the most stable when I use it in my other two body simulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is your frame inertial? Earth is constantly accelerating, so by forcing it to remain at $\mathbf{x}_4=0$, you must introduce fictitious forces to explain the other bodies.

The easy solution to your problem is this: *initialize* $\mathbf{x}_4=0$, but add another equation to let Earth evolve as well. You can always subtract $\mathbf{x}_4$ from all the vectors later to make Earth appear at zero in the future.

I don't think you gain anything from trying to glue Earth to the origin. You removed one ODE you need to solve, but the fictitious forces would probably be very complicated and would have to be recalculated every timestep, so you have to account for Earth's motion anyway. Fictitious forces help in problems like motion on the surface of the Earth, where things are symmetric and the rotation rate is constant. In an n-body simulation, I think it would just make things worse.